# How to check if a worksheet exists in an excel file

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am receiving an excel(Book1.xls) file from the user and sometimes one of the worksheets name is XYZ and sometimes its name is XYZ1.

I am doing

```
 Dim Conn,Rs   
 Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Conn.ConnectionTimeout = 10
 Conn.CommandTimeout = 300
 Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";"
 Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [XYZ$B1:B1]")
```

and when the worksheets name is XYZ1, the last line in the above code is blowing up with an error message:
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'XYZ$CB1:B1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'XYZ$CB1:B1' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Instead of the last line I would like to do something like

```
sheetNameString = Conn.Execute("SELECT Join(SheetName) from Book1.xls")

If InStr(sheetNameString,"XYZ1") Then
     Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [XYZ1$B1:B1]")
Else
     Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [XYZ$B1:B1]")
End If
```

Comment: Related: [Delete worksheet if it exists and create a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40206232/3357935)

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following code after the conn.open worked for me:

```
Dim Cat, Tbl, Tabs
Cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Cat.ActiveConnection = Conn
Tabs = Cat.Tables
For Each Tbl In Tabs
  'Tbl.Name holds the name
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to research, write and test so I was sure it worked. Didn't see the other answer.

Comment: Your answer was also helpful. No problem Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Steve - +1 because it is *tested* code (and not air code like mine).

Comment: Where do you define the worksheet name in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ADOX.Catalog" to get a list of the tables in a database:

```
Public Function getTableNames(oConn)
  Dim aRVal    : aRVal          = Array()
  Dim oCatalog : Set oCatalog   = CreateObject( "ADOX.Catalog" )
  Set oCatalog.ActiveConnection = oConn
  Dim oTable
  For Each oTable In oCatalog.Tables
      ReDim Preserve aRVal( UBound( aRVal ) + 1 )
      aRVal( UBound( aRVal ) ) = oTable.Name
  Next
  getTableNames = aRVal
End Function

If "XYZ1$" = getTableNames(Conn)(0) Then
     Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [XYZ1$B1:B1]")
Else
     Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM [XYZ$B1:B1]")
End If
```

(not tested, assumes just one sheet/table, needs improvements (e.g. `ReDim aRVal(oCatalog.Tables.Count - 1)` instead of `ReDim Preserve`), not sure whether the trailing $ will be kept)

**Another way:**

```
Public Function getTableNames(oConn)
  Const adSchemaTables = 20
  Dim oRS   : Set oRS = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
  Dim aRVal : aRVal   = Array()
  Do Until oRS.EOF
     ReDim Preserve aRVal(UBound(aRVal) + 1)
     aRVal(UBound(aRVal)) = oRS.Fields("TABLE_NAME").Value
     oRS.MoveNext
  Loop
  getTableNames = aRVal
End Function
```